# Open Dialog Box on Primefaces Error

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm having a error when i try to open dialog box on Primefaces, and i can't understand why this is happening.

Here my page code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./template/template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">
                <p:commandButton value="Abrir" oncomplete="w_dlgTeste.show()"/>
                <p:confirmDialog header="Erro desnecessário." message="Não estou a entender nada." widgetVar="w_dlgTeste" />
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

On google chrome `Javascript` console i see this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `onclick="PF('w_dlgTeste').show()"`. The error that appear there is because in Primefaces 4.0 and newer, the widgets are stored in a javascript widget array and you must call `PF('w_dlgTeste')` to return it from the array.

Apart from that, you can have a confirmDialog without content inside but it doesn't make any sense since you can't confirm anything. You should add confirmation buttons too.

If you want the simplest way, you can do it with only javascript:

```
<p:commandButton onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" .../>
```

**Edit:**

If what you want to do is to show a dialog confirmation, the best way you should do it is like [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml):

Using `p:confirm` in each button that you want a dialog confirmation:

```
<p:commandButton value="Abrir">
    <p:confirm header="Erro desnecessário." message="Não estou a entender nada." />
</p:commandButton>
```

And put the dialog with `global="true"` on your template because you probably want to reuse it:

```
<p:confirmDialog global="true">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Another option would be if what you want is just a simple information dialog after the action of the button you can do it like this too:

```
<p:commandButton value="Abrir" oncomplete="PF('w_dlgTeste').show()"/>
<p:dialog header="Erro desnecessário." widgetVar="w_dlgTeste">
    Não estou a entender nada.
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: I have tried and it do not work. On other hand, it will be better understand the problem, find the error and not make only work. Why this not work?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but this is happening for `confirmDialog` and `dialog`. Do you know why this don't work like a presented?

Comment: Check my answer now, note that if what you want is a confirmation dialog, you should put it inside an onclick, because oncomplete is executed after the action you want to do.

Comment: Sorry for my absence @mrganser, well, i'm using primefaces 3.5, and i've tried on other projects and it works as a presented, but i experimented the way you show(as primefaces showcases) and works, but i need understand why this happens sometimes.

Comment: @Cold Before 4.0 should work as you do, 4.0+ you must use PF('xxx') as explained in my answer, apart from that, I cannot think why you should face this error